# Cannot access my blockchain account

Tags: blockchain.info

Just recently opened a bitcoin wallet with Blockchain which I already funded. The problem is the wallet ID was not sent to my email and I already funded the account. I have  made several request for support to resend the wallet identifier to my email using the "remind me" tab all to no avail. Is there any other way I can access my account.

Comment: contact your vendor. This is not a problem pertaining Bitcoin.